# Add or focus to next input field when press keyboard ENTER button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am studying React and Material-ui.

I want to make several input fields within a component, the number and value of these fields are received as props from a parent component. I added a function to move the focus when a user press the Enter button, or create new field if its the last field.

The current code has 15 refs (I know it's stupid, but I think It'll not be more than 15). The problem is that the focus does not move to a new field when it is created. Can you suggest a better way?

```
class ResponseInput extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.refs = [...Array(15)].map(r => React.createRef())
    }

    changeFocus = index => {
        if (index < this.props.inputs.length - 1) {
            this.refs[index + 1].current.focus();
        } else {
            this.props.addInput();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { inputs, addInput, handleChangeInput } = this.props;

        return (
            <List>
                {inputs.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={index} >
                        <Input
                            value={item}
                            inputRef={this.refs[index]}
                            onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput (index, event)}
                            onKeyPress= {(event) => {
                                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                                    this.changeFocus(index);
                                }
                            }}
                            // autoFocus
                        />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/7wojmxv0oq

`<Input autoFocus={index+1>originalInputsLength} .../>`

Use `autoFocus={index+1>originalInputsLength}` checking which means if the input length exceeds original inputs length (user adding the list) then set autoFocus to that newly-created `<Input/>`.

`originalInputsLength` is initialized in App's constructor as state, then passed down as props to `<ResponseInput inputs={inputs} addInput={this.addInput} originalInputsLength={originalInputsLength}/>`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    const inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.state = {
      inputs: inputs,
      originalInputsLength: inputs.length,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `autoFocus={true}` to the `Input` should fix it.

```
render() {
    const { inputs, addInput, handleChangeInput } = this.props;

    return (
        <List>
            {inputs.map((item, index) => (
                <ListItem key={index} >
                    <Input
                        autoFocus={true}
                        value={item}
                        inputRef={this.refs[index]}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput (index, event)}
                        onKeyPress= {(event) => {
                            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                                this.changeFocus(index);
                            }
                        }}
                        // autoFocus
                    />
                </ListItem>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/10089vq54l

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I've already tried this, and I've given up this because I don't want the focus to move to the last field when I refresh. I'd be very grateful if you could suggest another way.

Comment: It gets a bit more complicated for this, as you need to keep some state and use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` to handle when it should allow focus or not. See https://codesandbox.io/s/8kppllw1z8